# how to adjust the weight loss in multi-task CNN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, linear-regression

I develop a multi-task CNN with 6 losses. I use BCEWithLogits Loss or MSE Loss to define these losses. I normalized the data by min-max feature scaling to values between 0 and 1.

The training and validation loss of some losses are not converging as other losses and the error is high. I tried to use random weight to improve the performance but got similar results.

```
 w = nn.functional.softmax(torch.randn(6), dim=-1)
 loss = w[0]*loss1 + w[1]*loss2 + w[2]*loss3   + w[3]*loss4 + w[4]*loss5 + w[5]*loss6
```

How can I adjust the weight to improve the results?

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing. Weights `w` DEFINE the performance target. By definition. These weights should be informed by your final performance metric (i.e. "accuracy"). How can you decouple poor convergence due to poor optimization / gradient / network structure from poorly tuned loss weights?

Comment: @DerekG the loss plot for each task shows that some losses converge from the 20 epoch while others are not. To balance different tasks I have applied the random weight from this paper 'A Closer Look at Loss Weighting in Multi-Task Learning. However, I got similar loss convergence. Therefore, I would like to find a way to adjust the loss weights.

Comment: Please find a different title with less potential to attract unwanted contributions, because "w..... l..." is what people who are not in the least interested in helping you or contributing to the community will jump on. It actually surprises me that it has not happened more often yet...